# mpeg to jpeg conversion and the opposite

Tags: c++, jpeg, mpeg

I am implementing a program and i need to ''break'' an MPEG video to jpeg frames and then back to an MPEG video. It is also needed that the application for the ''breaking''can be opened through my initial program. Any ideas?

Comment: You are in for a lot of work if you try to do it yourself. Check out https://www.ffmpeg.org/ - maybe you find some library helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick `convert` does the job very easily.

```
H:\temp\mpeg to frames>convert "SNL - Christopher Walken Cowbell.mpeg" x.jpg

H:\temp\mpeg to frames>dir /b x*.jpg | find /c /v ""
10540

H:\temp\mpeg to frames>_
```

The second command counts the number of result files, i.e. number of frames.

Frame number 2419 (the images are numbered by default):

[image]

Comment: Seems very interesting. So i run it like: system("H:\temp\mpeg to frames>convert "SNL - Christopher Walken Cowbell.mpeg" x.jpg");

Comment: @iol: Yes, except don't include the command interpreter prompt in the string you pass to `system`. There are also APIs for a number of programming languages, I believe also for C++. It's been a long time (like sixteen years or so) since I looked into that last, I don't exactly remember.

Answer (score 0):

The [avcodec library from ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/libavcodec.html) can do that. In fact, I did that exact thing with it.

When I used it (~5y ago), the documentation was almost non-existent, though. I'll try to dig up the code I wrote to give you a few pointers.